# How to configure seafile to run in HTTPS?

Tags: ssl-certificate, https

I've installed and configured seafile 1.6.1 on a debian squeeze. By default, it's working on http, port 8000.

To set up https, I added these 3 lines to `seafile.conf` (https://github.com/haiwen/seafile/wiki/Enable-Https-on-Seafile-web#wiki-Enable_https_on_seafile_httpserver):

```
https=true
pemfile=/path/seafile-data/conf/cacert.pem
privkey=/path/seafile-data/conf/privkey.pem
```

I modified `ccnet.conf` too:

```
SERVICE_URL = https://mycloud.mydomain.com:8000
```

I restarted the seafile and seahub.

As soon as I put these three lines, I can't get the login page anymore. I get a time out error message. As I verified, the connection is well established between my client and my server.

Anyone would have an idea of what's the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to configure correctly nginx to have seafile work on https:

```
server
{
    listen 443;
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/mycert.crt;    # path to your cacert.pem
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/mykey.key;     # path to your privkey.pem
    server_name mycloud.example.com;

    location / {

        fastcgi_pass    127.0.0.1:8000;
        fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME     $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param   PATH_INFO           $fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param   SERVER_PROTOCOL         $server_protocol;
        fastcgi_param   QUERY_STRING        $query_string;
        fastcgi_param   REQUEST_METHOD      $request_method;
        fastcgi_param   CONTENT_TYPE        $content_type;
        fastcgi_param   CONTENT_LENGTH      $content_length;
        fastcgi_param   SERVER_ADDR         $server_addr;
        fastcgi_param   SERVER_PORT         $server_port;
        fastcgi_param   SERVER_NAME         $server_name;
        fastcgi_param   HTTPS   on;

        access_log      /var/log/nginx/seahub.access.log;
        error_log       /var/log/nginx/seahub.error.log;
    }

    location /media {
        root /data/cloud/seafile-server-1.6.1/seahub;
    }
}
```

Greg.